# is gitlab caching global?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, cicd

we have an spring + angular app and ive tried caching the node_modules by adding these configurations to my gitlab-ci.yml file

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -P prod
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 800 mins 0 sec
    paths:
      - gateway/target/app.jar
      - gateway/target/Dockerfile
      - gateway/src/main/docker
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - gateway/node_modules # cache based on files and directories inside node_modules
    policy: pull-push
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != "master" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != "develop"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "push" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "push" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"'
```

but since our runners each run on a docker container and are stored as a volume for runner and im afraid only pipelines using the same runner will use the cache

is there a way to make it global?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _global_ -- do you mean just global across your _runners_ -- or having a cache that is global across all _projects_ or what?

Comment: each of my runners run on a container and their cache are stored inside their volume folder. but i want the cache to be available for all runners.

Answer (score 0):

For your cache to be available across runners on different hosts, you must configure [distributed caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching) on the runner. This way your cache can be uploaded and restored from any runner and different runners can use the same cache. This is automatically available on gitlab.com shared runners.

Without distributed caching enabled, caches are local to each host/runner.

Comment: unfortunately we can't do that at our company

Comment: Why not @HaniBikdeli ? You can [deploy minio alongside GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/advanced/external-object-storage/minio.html) (as seen in helm charts) to serve as the object storage if you don't want to use an external service like AWS S3.  The only other solution might be used network-attached storage for your configured cache storage, but you'll likely take other performance hits for that make it more harmful than helpful... If you can't do either, you cannot make your cache 'global' across different hosts/runners.

Comment: isnt there a way to store the cache on the server host os and tell gitlab to use that as cache? right now caches are stored in the runners volume folder and only that runner is using it

Comment: It depends a lot on your runner configuration, but yes it should be possible to do using volumes (configure both runners to mount the same path or use the same volume). Check out the [advanced configuration docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) @HaniBikdeli for that.